# Regex 0-4 ( between 0 and 4)

Tags: javascript, java

I’m trying to to create a Regex than accept 0,1,2,3,4 only. I have tried:

```
////d{0-3}|4
```

But it doesn’t work. Can you help me out?

Comment: Please share some code, to explain your problem, and choose betweekn Java and JS

Answer (score 2):

You need `[0-4]+` regex, in your example `\d` means every digit. See [example for [0-4]+` regex](https://regex101.com/r/IovJDx/1):

> 0-4 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 4 (index 52) (case sensitive)
>
> + Quantifier - Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something along the lines of

```
[0-4]
```

There are some excellent examples [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). Scroll down to nearly the bottom of the page, there are examples of how the various range selections (not the right term for them) work.